# UINavigationController is not pushing the Contentview down on IOS7

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7

So. Just started transitioning my IOS code to IOS7, and ran into a bit of problem.

I have a UINavigationController which hold a ViewController in it, which have two buttons in a view.
In IOS prior to 7 the Navigation bar pushed the view down to be beneath the navigation bar and that way I could see it. In IOS 7 the UINavigationController doesn't do it and the buttons are placed behind the navigation bar.

Here is the IOS 7:
 [image: IOS 7 display without the VC]

and here is the old IOS 6 view:

[image: IOS 6 image]

I checked the ViewController.view.frame.origin.y and saw that its begin on 0px (on IOS 7) 
I am sure that it is there but behind the view as I have change the origin of the buttons and saw them.

Comment: Check the ios7 transition guide on extended edges

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just ran into the same problem. Try putting this code in your init:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

This is mentioned in the iOS 7 transition guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html

A more concise explanation is here: http://www.brianjcoleman.com/ios7-weve-got-a-problem/